# CAShapelayer Masking

Tags: objective-c

I have 3 CAShapelayers inside a bigger CAShapelayer.Say rectangle,triangle inside a big rectangle and all these CAShapelayers are drawn over an image.I need to fill the bigger rectangle with a pattern image but all the other 2 shapes needn't be filled.
            I have tried masking, evenodd rule.Please help . Currently I am getting the exact opposite .Filling the inner layers not outer
 This is what I am doing

```
// mask layer is the outer layer
         CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
                            maskLayer.fillRule = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd;
                            maskLayer.frame = self.view.frame;


//inner layer1                       
     CAShapeLayer *maskSubLayer1 = [CAShapeLayer layer];
                            maskSubLayer1.fillRule = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd;
                            maskSubLayer1.frame = self.view.frame;


 //inner layer 2              
              CAShapeLayer *maskSubLayer2 = [CAShapeLayer layer];
                            maskSubLayer2.fillRule = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd;
                            maskSubLayer2.frame = self.view.frame;


 //shapelayer and shapelayer 2 are the exact layer that are drawn inside         
 // add the paths to sublayers of the mask
                            maskSubLayer1.path = shapeLayer.path;
                            maskSubLayer2.path = shapeLayer2.path;

                            [maskLayer addSublayer:maskSubLayer1];
                            [maskLayer addSublayer:maskSubLayer2];

  // masking the outer layer                 
           biggershapeLayer.mask = maskLayer;
            [biggershapeLayer setFillColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[imagesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]].CGColor];
                            [self.view.layer addSublayer:biggershapeLayer];


   *******************************************
   *                                         *
   *                                         *
   *    *******             ******           *
   *    ********            ******           * 
   *     *******            ******           * 
   *      *******           ******           * 
   *                                         *
   *******************************************

This is the current result I want the exact opposite.
```

Comment: Can you show what you tried? What that resulted in and what you are expecting? Also, did any of the "CAShapeLayer + mask" questions do what you are looking for? If not, why is your case different?

Comment: I have formed a UIBezier path for outer layer and all the inner shapes and assign that bezier path to a cashapelayer with fill rule even odd.

Comment: but those are different paths? even-odd file rule works no the same path overlapping itself

Comment: can u suggest a sample code code for me , I'll be extremely helpful .

Comment: I can attch images , but the site shows I need atleast 10 reputation.

Comment: CGMutablePathRef p1 = CGPathCreateMutable();
                CGPathAddPath(p1, NULL, shapeLayer.path);
                CGPathAddPath(p1, NULL, shapeLayer2.path);
                maskWithHole.path = p1;
 [maskWithHole setFillRule:kCAFillRuleEvenOdd];
                [maskWithHole setFillColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[imagesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]].CGColor];
                [[self.image layer] addSublayer:maskWithHole];   I have tried this too